# Why do I get a "Errno 10057 socket error" in python?

Tags: python, sockets

When I the progrem below between two computers running Python on the same wifi, i get the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Server.EX.py", line 10, in <module>
        des1 = s.recv(1024)
    socket.error: [Errno 10057] A request to send or receive data was     
    disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a 
    datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

The program Server.py runs on one computer:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((///Computer 1 IP///, 1729))
s.listen(1)
conn, address = s.accept()
print("Connection started.Enter 0 to finish connection.")
des1 = 1
while des1 != 0:
    des1 = s.recv(1024)
    print(des1)
    conn.send(raw_input("SERVER: "))
conn.close()
s.close()
```

The program Client.py runs on the second computer:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((///Computer 1 IP///, 1729))
print("Connection started. Enter 0 to finish connection.")
des1 = 1
while des1 != 0:
    s.send(raw_input("CLIENT: "))
    des1 = s.recv(1024)
    print(des1)
s.close()
```

Can someone help me with that please (-:

*notice that ///Computer 1 IP/// is an actual IPv4 address

Answer (score 0):

A server socket (`s`, in your server.py) exists only to accept client connections; the return value of `.accept()` includes the connected socket (`conn` in your code) that you will use for all communication with that particular client.  You are correctly using `conn` for calling `.send()`, but are incorrectly using `s` to call `.recv()`.

Comment: changed it thanks but now there is this problem:

    socket.error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address 
    (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Comment: A particular address/port combination is considered in use for a period of time after a socket is closed, to handle any lingering network traffic that might arrive for it.  Put `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` immediately after the creation of the socket to turn off this feature.